# What does an overflow mean?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

While I debug my flutter app, at certain points I see warnings like this:

- `Bottom overflow by 1234 pixel`
- `BoxConstraints have a negative value`

I suppose, my concept of Flutter viewport / layout isn't correct:

> Currently, I image an infinite drawing area, where I declaratively
> define widgets.
>
> Widgets, which are too large, get drawn outside the
> viewport [or clipped].

**Could you please refine my probably wrong concept?**

Comment: Can you please share code that causes this error so it would be easier to explain by example?

Comment: You might wanna check [this] out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This happens when the size `[height, width]` exceeds the the total size of the screen.**
For example : the aspect ratio `height` of mobile screen is 500 and the `size.height` of button is 600, then the Bottom overflow by 100 pixel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But does that is an error that somehow makes the app useless? Or just a warning, that some part of the UI might be non reachable e.g.?

Comment: No that's not an error but that will effect your UI elements.  you can still build your application with that. but you will face "UI Error message" on the UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

Generally overflow means, that the widget you want to paint on the screen crosses the border of the screen and therefore isn't visible anymore... This can also happen if you implement non scrollable columns in containers of a certain height... Usually, you can wrap your widget in a SingleChildScrollView widget and as a child choose a column/row (depending on the direction you want it to be aligned...) or make a list view and set the scrolldirection property to Axis.vertical or Axis.horizontal...